# what is the maximum number for a ruby big decimal in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigdecimal, records

My RoR is currently giving me some problems for Bigdecimal records.

my code is to update certain attribute with:

```
 BigDecimal.new((income*scale).to_s)
```

For example there is a form that I scanned and its value is

```
 11210000000.0
```

when i print the bigdecimal it looks like:

```
 #<BigDecimal:91e2284,'0.1121E11',18(27)>
```

when i look the record in mySQL db the record appears with

```
  Income: 9999999999
```

all the records with income less than 10 billion do not have this problem.

What is going on?

Comment: i think BigDecmial max will be different on 32 or 64 bit machines - what data type is your mySQL field - the issue might be there? - might be helpful: http://torontoprogrammer.ca/2010/05/decimal-numbers-in-rails-and-mysql/

Comment: the data type is decimal. using a 64bit machine.

Comment: are the precision and scale set correctly on the decimal column?

Comment: Sweet! I ran a migration where I changed the type from :decimal to :decimal, :precision => 16, :scale => 2 and now it works just fine. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

wrote this in the terminal:

```
 rails g migration change_income_format_in_my_table
```

then set the migration file as:

```
class ChangeIncomeFormatInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def up
change_table :forms do |t|
  t.change :income, :decimal, :precision => 16, :scale => 2
end
 end

 def down
    change_table :forms do |t|
     t.change :income, :decimal
   end
 end
  end
```

then typed

```
rake db:migrate
```

thanks [house9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317989/house9)

Answer (score 1):

I think (because I can't find it in the docs but I know it's the case for Integer) that BigDecimal has no MAX value in Ruby. Unfortunately all database systems have those limits so you may wish to store big numbers as strings in the database.